# Optimum configuration for 4 SSD drives

Tags: sql-server, performance, configuration, hardware

I would like to move a SQL Server database from a shared configuration with the web-server to it's own dedicated box. My current budget will allow me to put 4 disks together in an array with a single hot spare. I'd like to stretch to 8+ drives but the costs are a little out of my budget right now (and probably somewhat overkill).

So my question is, what would be the optimum configuration for SQL Server 2012 when limited to 4 disks? The database is around 29 GB and is growing around 250-500 MB per month. The database will typically deliver 80% reads to 20% inserts/updates/deletes.

I understand from researching this subject that my options are as follows:

1. **RAID 5** with all functions on a single volume.
2. **Dual RAID 1** with OS, Backups and system dbs on one volume and database + log files on the other.
3. **RAID 10** with all function on a single volume.

I'm looking for a solution that will give me reasonable performance but won't obliterate the array if a single drive fails (which I understand is quite common with SSDs).

**Current Hardware ------------------**

HP ProLiant DL360 G7 1 x Xeon E5640 / 2.66 GHz - RAM 12 GB - 2 x 300GB Pluggable SAS SFF 10,000 rpm disks in RAID 1.

Comment: The missing information here is what kind of hardware the DB/web-server is currently running on? ie how many disks, what configuration and whether they are SSD or not.

Comment: Current hardware details updated (see above). I should add that unless under heavy load this configuration holds up pretty well.

Comment: I think my suggestion would be similar to COTW's then, go for some *good* SSDs like the s3700 (or possibly the s3500 coming out next month). I'd just get two and put everything on a RAID1: the step up from your SAS array will be so enormous you really don't need to worry about making marginal gains with a more complex setup. Personally with that growth rate, I'd provision for 5 years and then double it at least so would want to get 2x200GB drives. Do drop by [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) if you'd like to chat more.

Comment: This strikes me a as a rare and very welcome [way to do business](http://support.quickfile.co.uk/why_is_quickfile_free.htm): I wish you every success with that!

Comment: Thanks Jack, I agree that a simple RAID 1 SSD array would be a massive leap forward in performance over the old single server config. With this setup I could even acquire two servers for additional db redundancy and keep the old box serving the web-tier. As you see from our biz model, there's an imperative to be resourceful here.

Comment: Have you considered hosting? I have a hosting environment that would be suitable, but whether it would be cost effective or not may depend on how you are licensing SQL Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With spinning-platter disks you want to have the logs and data on separate drives as random access data disrupts the sequential log write operations, making the logs a performance bottleneck.  SSDs do not have this issue as they lack the performance constraints imposed by the mechanical action of conventional hard disks.

If you're getting SSDs for a DB server, get ones designed for a long life span, such as Intel S3700s.  You're probably better off getting two of those than four cheaper ones, and 2x100GB units + a hot spare (which is probably enough to keep you going for a few years at your current rate of growth) should cost around £200 each according to Google Shopping.

Mixing logs and data on the same disks isn't such a big deal any more.  However, you may get some resiliency out of having separate log drives.  If you want to do this then 5 disks (enough for two pairs + a hot spare) should still see you with change out of £1,000.

Try two good quality drives in a RAID-1, with a hot spare for a starter.  Your growth suggests you probably won't have transaction volumes so high that this setup can't keep up with your application workload.

Back up your database onto spinning disks - a couple of enterprise-grade SATA disks and a hot spare should cost you a few hundred dollars.

If (and only if) you have performance problems with that lot then you might look into adding more SSDs, but I suspect just one pair will be fast enough to keep up with your transaction volumes quite comfortably.

Comment: Depending on volume etc. you may also want to look into adaptec raid controllers and their hybrid raid 10 - one ssd paired with one platter, all reads going to the ssd. That is to keep a server running instead of going the still more expensive full ssd, in case of a failure. Doing that now with a 2tb size database.

Comment: @TomTom I think LSI [have something similar](http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/SolidState.aspx)

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Usage of SSD cache is not identical - this is Hybrid Raid. Uses a lot more SSD size... thus more expensive. It is not on board - it is "mirror hard disc with ssd and have all reads go to the SSD". As scuch, I can scale it as large as I scale the raid - obviously for a little price of having 50% in SSD. Caches are good, but when you do data warehouse size stuff, they get - ah - small ;)

Comment: @TomTom I understand now, thanks, but tbh I'm dubious about going that route: cost is never less than half the full-ssd cost and complexity is higher, I'm not sure if that is a worthwhile trade-off. The [adaptec docs](http://www.adaptec.com/nr/pdfs/hybrid-raid_wp.pdf) also leave me feeling a bit uneasy for some reason.

Comment: Well, the alternative is 2x ssd - that is VERY expensive ;)

Comment: If your workload consists of a lot of random IO (which is likely for a database server), I strongly recommend ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells' suggestion over a hybrid solution. Random write performance to a single SSD can rival that of entire trays of spinning discs, and you won't suddenly drop to spinning-disc speeds if your SSD fails.